# sencha phonegap cannot bind to json

Tags: javascript, extjs, datastore

I think I have read all the issues regarding sencha phonegap and json.

However I would like to seek help on how to bind my JSON in my device. In Chrome it's working perfectly, but when I compile it using Eclipse, it becomes dead when it comes to binding to the JSON data. I got a simple textfield, put value then filter the store. but nothing is happening.

My device is running android 2.1, all my `.js` and `.json` files are under the folder `assets/www`:

```
//sample store
var bogus = new Ext.data.Store({
  model: 'Dictionary',
      autoLoad:true,
      proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url:'bogus.json',
      reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'table_t'
          }
      }
}); 


//** heres my action event in searchfield
//** programmatically changes the json data
bogus.proxy.url = 'another.json';

bogus.load();//then load

Ext.getCmp('mylist').bindStore( bogus );/* this becomes dead :(   */
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you having problem with offline JSON, you can edit your `sencha-debug.js` and look for this:  on `Ext.data.Connection.onComplete`,

then change the first if statement to:

```
if ((status >= 200 && status < 300) || status == 304 || 
  (status == 0 && r.xhr.responseText.length > 0) ) {
```

the fix came from joelmay from sencha forum.  Thanx.